# Create a symbol with brackets in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a symbol in ruby with brackets. For example when I do the following:

```
2.0.0p247 :007 >  {hello: "something"}
 => {:hello=>"something"}
```

This should be fine. However if I wanted to do "`hello[]`" as the symbol how would I do this?

Comment: Why do you want a sym with brackets, though?

Comment: because its actually a parameter in a url (stupid but that how their API works). so I'm using it in `RestClient.get url, {params:{ param1: 'test'}}`. The problem is that `param1` is actually `param1[]`.

Comment: And the string version doesn't work? Interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surround the name of the symbol in quotes:

```
:'hello[]'
```